# How do I convert a single dataframe column to a dictionary for each row with the column name as the key?

Tags: python, dataframe, dictionary, spacy

I want to use the Doc extension functionality from Spacy. I need to convert dataframe columns into tuples consisting of text only and a dictionary with column name value pairs.

Using pandas dataframe.to_dict(orient='records') comes close but doesn't allow me to use only 1 column or select specific columns. Applying the to_dict() method to a single dataframe column also doesn't get me closer to the desired layout. Should I take a different approach?

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({
    'Textitself': ['Just a text'],
    'Textkey': [502]
})
otherlayout = df.to_dict('records')
print(otherlayout)
```

Below you find the format I try to obtain.

```
desired_format = [('Just a text',{'Textkey' : 502 }), ('One more text', {'Textkey' : 103 })]

print(desired_format)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's one way of doing it:

```py
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({
    'Textitself': ['Just a text','One more text'],
    'Textkey': [502, 103]
})
otherlayout = df.to_dict('records')
print(otherlayout)

desiredformat = [(i,dict(j)) for i,j in df.set_index("Textitself").iterrows()]
print(desiredformat)
```

output is

```py
[{'Textitself': 'Just a text', 'Textkey': 502}, {'Textitself': 'One more text', 'Textkey': 103}]


[('Just a text', {'Textkey': 502}), ('One more text', {'Textkey': 103})]
```

Comment: Great, output is exactly what I was looking for and  code looks really condense. I do want to understand what is happening. Can you  elaborate a little what happens?

Comment: sure, I'm using `list comprehension` to create a list. I'm using `set_index` to extract one columns value and use it as first element of a tuple. And I'm using `dict(` to convert all remaining elements into key-value pairs. If output matches what you want - please feel free to "accept" and "upvote" the answer! :)

Comment: Thanks, now I do not only have an answer but also some guidance to find more background information.